# Dynamic quarterly reports for 250 clients - Crystal Reports or other tool?

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, report, visualization, import-from-excel

I'm looking to create a 2-3 page PDF report for a list of 250 clients.

The data is originally obtained from an Excel spreadsheet.

What I need to do essentially is import that Excel data into a tool (Crystal Reports or a better option?), and have it generate 250 PDF documents based on a predesigned template.

The 250 clients are clearly indicated within the originating Excel speadsheet.

I'm not an advanced Crystal Reports user, so I'm not even sure if this is possible using Crystal Reports. My questions are, would Crystal Reports be a good fit for this project, and if not what are some alternatives I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal could be quite a good solution for this, although it is somewhat objective and you will need a third party tool (or to design something yourself) to take care of the splitting out to separate clients.

Do you need any pointers?

You can most likely approach 1 of 2 ways:

- Create a report which will contain all of the data and then said 3rd party or home-made tool will split into many smaller reports
- Create a report which is executed once per client using said 3rd party or home-made tool

Comment: Thank you kindly for your answer. I was hoping that there would be a way to split the reports into 250 PDFs using the CrystalReports tool itself without relying on a custom implementation. I could definitely use some pointers on how to achieve this customely if it is not possible within Crystal Reports.